# b:navLink action is never invoked

Tags: jsf, action, navbar, bootsfaces

I'm currently writing a webapp using bootfaces.  In my application I have a top navigation bar like the following

```
        <b:navBar brand="Brand" brandHref="#" inverse="true">
            <b:navbarLinks>
                <b:navLink value="Home" href="#"></b:navLink>
                <b:navLink value="Link" href="#"></b:navLink>
                <b:navLink value="Link" href="#"></b:navLink>

                <b:dropMenu value="#{loginBean.username}">
                    <b:navLink value="Logout" action="#{loginBean.doLogout}"/>
                </b:dropMenu>
            </b:navbarLinks>
        </b:navBar>
```

Notice action="#{loginBean.doLogout}"

With primefaces, this works no problem, but when I migrated to bootfaces doLogout is never executed.  Is there another binding I need to use in bootfaces to make this action get executed?

Answer (score 3):

Seems that the [new BootsFaces version](http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/whats-new-in-bootsfaces-0-7-0/) adds a new component (b:navCommandLink) so it behaves like a commandLink.

Comment: This looks great, but it appears b:navCommandLink isn't in the taglib, I have yet to find an updated tag lib to use for 0.7.0

Comment: I'm pretty sure b:navCommandLink is in the taglib - I just looked it up, and it works on our showcase. However, maybe you've detected an error that missed my eye. Would you mind to prepare a small GitHub project (or upload a zipped project, or something like that) which reproduces the error and open a bug on out [bugtracker](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues)? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I needed to do the following

```
<b:navLink value="Logout" href="#{loginBean.doLogout()}"/>
```

Comment: And that it's invoked during page load is not an issue to you?